# Solarium execute custom query

Tags: php, solr, solarium

How can I execute query `/solr/<core>/schema/fields` or any direct uri in Solarium?
I found some codes but I don't know how to use them:

```
$request = $client->createRequest($query);
$response = $client->executeRequest($request);
$result = $client->createResult($query, $response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file_get_contents('/your/endpoint')` to query a solr-uri. If you need to do POST to an endpoint you Guzzle.